# In time-partitioned bigquery tables, when is data written to __UNPARTITIONED__? what are the effects?

Tags: google-bigquery

I ran into some freak undocumented behavior of time-partitioned bigquery tables:

I created a time-partitioned table in BigQuery and inserted data.
I was able to insert normally - data was written to today's partition (I was also able to explicitly specify a partition and write into it)

After some tests with new data, I deleted today's partition, in order to have clean data:(CLI)

```
bq --project_id=my-project rm v1.mytable$20160613
```

I then checked whether it's empty:

```
select count(*) from [v1.mytable]
```

**Result** 270 instead of 0

I tried deleting again and rerunning the query - same result.
So I queried

```
select count(*) from [v1.mytable$20160613]
```

**Result** 0

so a couple of previous dates in which I may have inserted data, but all were 0. 
Finally I ran

```
SELECT partition_id from [v1.mytable$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__];
```

and the **result** was

{ **UNPARTITIONED**  20160609    20160613 }

and all the data was in fact in **UNPARTITIONED**

**My questions:**

1. When is the data written to this special partition instead of the daily partition, and how can I avoid this?
2. Are there other effects, except from losing the ability to address specific dates (in query, or when deleting data, etc.)? should I take care for this case?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_partitioned_tables
Documentation states: When there's enough unpartitioned data, the data is partitioned to the corresponding partitions

Answer (score 8):

1. While data is in the streaming buffer, it remains in the UNPARTITIONED partition. To address this partition in a query, you can use the value NULL for the _PARTITIONTIME pseudo column.

   `SELECT ... FROM mydataset.mypartitioned_table WHERE _PARTITIONTIME IS NULL`
2. To delete data for a given partition, we suggest doing a write truncate to it with a query that returns an empty result. For example:

   `bq query --destination_table=mydataset.mypartitionedtable\$20160121 --replace 'SELECT 1 as field1, "one" as field2 FROM (SELECT 1 as field1, "one" as field2) WHERE FALSE'`

Note that the partition will still be around (if you do  a SELECT * from table$__PARTITIONS__SUMMARY), but it will have 0 rows.

```
$ bq query 'SELECT COUNT(*) from [mydataset.mypartitionedtable$20160121]'

+-----+
| f0_ |
+-----+
|   0 |
+-----+
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a temporary state -- querying an hour later the records all belonged to today's partition.

The effect is thus similar to a delay in data write: querying immediately after the insert may not have the most recent data in the correct partition, but eventually this will be ok